# Markers won't show on Gmaps from my Google Drive coordinates

Tags: html, google-maps, google-drive-api

I have a spreadsheet in Google drive with the 'Name', 'Lat', 'Lng' and 'Pop' of various cities worldwide. I created a DoGet Function with the following script:

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = '0ArgTJt0LQs91dFNXNnk1ZXVjTlE0SmE1MVFpTE5GQUE';
var SHEET_NAME = 'Data';

function doGet(request) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    var cities = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) 
    {
        var city = {
            name: values[i][0],
            latlng: [values[i][1], values[i][2]],
            population: values[i][3]
        };
        cities.push(city);
    }

    var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(cities);

    if (request && request.parameters) {
        var callback = request.parameters.jsonp;
        if (callback) {
            json = callback + '(' + json + ')';
        }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Then I deployed as web app with the following URL: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwZyZI0saAdAruEYtvKDb0r1WofVfVzi7XIi6YQzq0s4BJqhnDZ/exec

Below is the script with my data service url. Only the map will show without the markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Awesome Map</title>

    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      #map_canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
       var DATA_SERVICE_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwZyZI0saAdAruEYtvKDb0r1WofVfVzi7XIi6YQzq0s4BJqhnDZ/exec?jsonp=callback";

      var map;

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          zoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 20,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = DATA_SERVICE_URL;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
      }

      function callback(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][3], data[i][2]),
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array-indices start with 0, you use the wrong items when you create the marker-position.

This works for me:

```
    function callback(data) {
      //note: i is set to 1, because the first row contains the column-names
      for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][1], data[i][2]),
          title:data[i][0],
          map: map
        });
      }      
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reaction but after applying your changes It's still not working.

Comment: You serve the script with the wrong Mime-type(has to be JAVASCRIPT instead of JSON), most browsers did not execute scripts when served with the wrong MIME-Type

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and IE with the JSON Mime-type. The tutorial I used said it needs to be JSON https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS2Nj5G9cGs @ 2:38 How can I make this work or change it into Java so it will automatically display the markers from the coordinates I put in my Gdrive?

Comment: The tutorial isn't correct, the MIME-type must be `text/javascript`. You will e.g. in chrome get the following error: *Refused to execute script from [script-url] because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.* To send the correct MIME-Type use `.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT)` Demo with correct Mime-Type: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/mLGQW/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/mLGQW/)

Comment: Note: don't use the script-URL from the demo in your script, it's my own macro and will not reflect changes in your spreadSheet.

Comment: I changed  return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); to return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT); What else am I missing??

Comment: You probably must create a new project-version

Comment: I am looking very hard at everything possible that could be wrong with my scripts or spreadsheet but no, creating a project version still didn't showed the markers.

Comment: You must also publish the project with the new version

Comment: Still nothing, can you show me your script because I am using the example from : https://gist.github.com/saxman/5101960 with the only change the Mimetype set to javascript as you suggested and my own URL ofcourse

Comment: my script is equal to the script you've posted in your question, the only difference is the MIME-Type

Comment: var json = callback + '(' + Utilities.jsonStringify(range.getValues()) + ')'; leads
in the test web app for your latest code in Google drive to the undefined error but the markers showing.

var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(cities);won't give the undefined error but leads to the markers disappearing off the map